# 403 error, openam not redirecting to url after authentication

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openam

When trying to access a secured url, it redirected to OpenAM login page as expcted. But after login, is am getting 403 error with the following url in browser. 
I have set 'Agent Filter Mode' as 'SSO_ONLY' for 'MagentoWebServices-1'.

http://10.132.253.22:8080/agentapp/sunwCDSSORedirectURI?goto=http%3A%2F%2F10.132.253.22%3A8080%2FMagentoWebServices-1%2F

Please find details in agents log below:

```
amIdm:12/06/2016 12:15:04:589 PM IST: Thread[main,5,main]
ERROR: IdUtils.initialize: Loading default types.
Message:The user does not have permission to perform the operation.

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient$SOAPContentHandler.createResourceBasedException(SOAPClient.java:855)
at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient$SOAPContentHandler.endDocument(SOAPClient.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endDocument(AbstractSAXParser.java:745)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:515)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:346)
at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:315)
at com.sun.identity.sm.jaxrpc.SMSJAXRPCObject.read(SMSJAXRPCObject.java:121)
at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.read(SMSEntry.java:704)
at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.read(SMSEntry.java:681)
at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.<init>(SMSEntry.java:475)
at com.sun.identity.sm.CachedSMSEntry.getInstance(CachedSMSEntry.java:382)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigImpl.checkAndUpdatePermission(ServiceConfigImpl.java:625)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigImpl.getInstance(ServiceConfigImpl.java:509)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigImpl.getInstance(ServiceConfigImpl.java:464)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigManagerImpl.getGlobalConfig(ServiceConfigManagerImpl.java:201)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigManager.getGlobalConfig(ServiceConfigManager.java:253)
at com.sun.identity.idm.IdUtils.initialize(IdUtils.java:131)
at com.sun.identity.idm.IdUtils.<clinit>(IdUtils.java:119)
at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealm.initPrivilegedAttributeTypes(AmRealm.java:100)
at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealm.initialize(AmRealm.java:71)
at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.ServiceFactory.getAmRealm(ServiceFactory.java:165)
at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealmManager.<init>(AmRealmManager.java:49)
at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealmManager.<clinit>(AmRealmManager.java:139)
at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.<clinit>(AmTomcatRealm.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:117)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1184)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)


amFilter:12/06/2016 12:15:57:705 PM IST: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-4,5,main]
ERROR: LibertyAuthnResponseHandler : Response received from an untrusted      provider - http://mynetwork:8100/OpenAM-13.0.0/cdcservlet
amFilter:12/06/2016 12:15:57:706 PM IST: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-4,5,main]
ERROR: CDSSOResultTaskHandler : One or more AuthnResponse conditions might  not have been met. Denying  to requested URI - /agentapp/sunwCDSSORedirectURI
amFilter:12/06/2016 12:16:23:688 PM IST: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-7,5,main]
ERROR: LibertyAuthnResponseHandler : Response received from an untrusted  provider - http://mynetwork:8100/OpenAM-13.0.0/cdcservlet
amFilter:12/06/2016 12:16:23:689 PM IST: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-7,5,main]
ERROR: CDSSOResultTaskHandler : One or more AuthnResponse conditions might   not have been met. Denying  to requested URI - /agentapp/sunwCDSSORedirectURI
amAgentCore:12/06/2016 12:19:22:447 PM IST: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-9,5,main]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: LibertyAuthnResponseHandler : Response received from an untrusted      provider - http://mynetwork:8100/OpenAM-13.0.0/cdcservlet

You need to update the property "CDSSO Servlet URL" in the agent profile and add the URL the agent is complaining about. This is either caused by OpenAM multi-instance setup or usage of HTTP RPs, etc.